# Twython -TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm trying to create a bot that will retweet and promote some of my other accounts. But i receive the below error.

```
for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

My code is...

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

app_key = 'KEY'
app_secret = 'KEY'
oauth_token = 'KEY'
oauth_token_secret = 'KEY'

twitter = Twython(app_key,app_secret,oauth_token,oauth_token_secret)

#Setting Twitter's search results as a variable
search_results = twitter.get_user_timeline(sreen_name="SCREENNAME", count = 2,)

try:
    for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
        twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])
except TwythonError as e:
    print e
```

Comment: The error seems clear: `search_results` is a list, not a dict.

Comment: Sorry i'm  newbie and just trying to get to learn a bit of coding... Could you suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation `get_user_timeline` function returns last n timeline stories as a list. Here, n is passed as `count` key word argument.

So, the problem is that you are trying index a list with a string. which is not possible.So that is causing the problem.
This [Link](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/special_functions.html) can help you move forward.